# Go error installing dependency, producing EOF

Tags: go, eof, go-modules, go-toolchain

I have just received a new notebook with Win onboard (21H2 build 19044.1415) and tried to install my Go project. After running `go build` I just keep receiving EOF errors.

I tried to sync dependencies in Jetbrains Goland, in VS Code (it is saying EOF when trying to install gopls) or just in plain command line - the result is the same everywhere. Please see the following error:

`go get github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4 go: module github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go/v4/@v/list": EOF`

Any ideas ho to fix it would be welcome.

Comment: What version of Go are you using? When I run the `go get ...` with 1.18 on my windows machine it works. Can you give us the output of `go env` as well?

Comment: Just rerun the command.

Comment: since you confirmed this was a networking issue, I'm going to mark the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. The problem was in wifi network I was connected to. There were some proxy servers that prevented dependencies from downloading (maybe GONOPROXY, GOPROXY, GONOSUMDB should be tweaked in this case). I connected to another network and everything was fine. Spent an hour or two trying to find out the problem though. Error message should definetely be changed to smth more informative.